# Referral invites with Amazon Cognito

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, referrals

Building an mobile application and it is heavily dependent on referral codes/invites on the first few months

We are using aws cognito for all user signin/up processes. What would be the best way to implement referral codes/invites (Same as uber/lyft etc) with aws cognito? Or scrap cognito and use firebase because it contains both user functions as well as dynamic links

Comment: Pre-Sign up lambda trigger is the way to go. More information the Pr-sign up lambda trigger - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add a pre sign up lambda function. This will allow you to validate during the sign up of a user that they have a valid referral link.